# How to retrieve web Url from Glide cache image/icon file?

Tags: android, android-glide

Glide saves images/icons in this local app directory image_manager_disk_cache e.g. file path

/data/user/0/com.app.abc/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/88cf36166efa4e8d963049b82000f615204ae89c7a37062e5b95a0ee76895449.0

how could retrieve the actual web URL from this hash code key? 88cf36166efa4e8d963049b82000f615204ae89c7a37062e5b95a0which is in directory ee76895449.0

How does Glide prepare this hash-code from web url? how to decode this hash-key back to web url? #android #glide

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this problem?

Comment: decode bitmap image then show on imageview

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is virtually impossible - the whole point of a hash function is to be unrecoverable and irreversible(at least on the current generations of computing machines). The main reason is that multiple different values can result in the same hash(you can search for more info about this online or check [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/45390))

You can achieve one-to-one mapping manually, though. You should have your own map of <URL_string,hash_string> stored somewhere and fill it with the URL you know and its hash counterpart at the time when you do have your URL. Glide uses the same approach internally, but its API is private. They have a special map object for such a purpose, [`CachedHashCodeArrayMap`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/util/CachedHashCodeArrayMap.java). They use it inside the [`Options`](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/load/Options.java#L12) class for better performance in fetching cached images. While you can access private properties via [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html), I wouldn't suggest it - it is better to have your own mechanism that stores the map somewhere you control.

[Here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/util/Util.java) are their hashing algorithms.